# CSS image gallery with name at bottom of image

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I am trying to make an image gallery with the name of the image sitting inside the image at the bottom of it. I have been unsuccessful so far.

Picture of desired result:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!-- start content -->
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='photo'>
            <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
            <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class='photo'>
            <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
            <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class='photo'>
            <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
            <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class='photo'>
            <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
            <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class='photo'>
            <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
            <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    background-color: #404040;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.photo {
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 298px;
    height: 298px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.photo-name {
    /*margin-top: 245px;*/
    /*padding: 0.5em;*/
    text-align: center;
    background-color: cyan;
    /*background-color: #666666;*/
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/h3x2ooax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give that text element an absolute position, 100% width and the desired `bottom` setting for the distance from the bottom border:

```
.photo-name {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1mp8k1by/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the element was not visible?

Comment: yes: it's BEHIND the image - try to add `.photo img { display: none; }`, then you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

Your text needs to be in `position: absolute` to be visible, see this snippet :

```css
.content {
 background-color: #404040;
 width: 940px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.photo {
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 298px;
 height: 298px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.photo-name {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #666666;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
 <!-- start content -->
 <div class='content'>
  <div class='photo'>
   <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
   <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class='photo'>
   <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
   <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class='photo'>
   <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
   <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class='photo'>
   <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
   <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class='photo'>
   <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
   <div class='photo-name'>Name</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- end content -->
```

The updated JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3x2ooax/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `position: relative;` to the .photo element.

And set `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` to the photo's name element

You can change the property `bottom` to increase or decrease the distance to the bottom of the image

https://jsfiddle.net/v4j0a628/